# I sent USDT to the wrong solana tag

Tags: solana

I sent USDT from Binance to Solana, but I entered the wrong tag. The operation has already been completed.  Is there any way to get this money back and how?

Answer (score 2):

If by `tag` you mean a wallet address, once you do a transfer there is no getting it back unless you own the address you sent it to.

If you know the owner of where it was sent, you can ask them to send it back.